# if/else condition is not working as expected

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

```
WebElement radio= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"mydiv\"]/form/div[1]/div[3]/label"));

if (radio.isSelected()){
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mydiv\"]/form/div[1]/div[2]/label")).click();
} else { 
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mydiv\"]/form/div[1]/div[3]/label")).click();
}
```

This is code I am using but it is always selecting the else statement even when the condition is true.

Answer (score 3):

**Note : I am giving my suggestion in Answer as I do not have sufficient reputation to be able to comment.**

First do not use thread sleep.

Second put some implicit or explicit wait between your element finding and if condition statements.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are missing out on the asterisk or the tag details, 
`//*` selects all elements in a document, regardless of name, or you could provide the tag name (input, span, table, etc).

Try this code:

```
WebElement radio= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mydiv']/form/div[1]/div[3]/label"));
```

or

```
WebElement radio= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//TagName[@id='mydiv']/form/div[1]/div[3]/label"));
```